# BeginGetResponse in web application

Tags: c#, multithreading, .net-3.5

I want to use the BeginGetResponse method in order to call many URLs which I hold on a list.
I have 2 questions on how to implement this:

1. according to the example in http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.httpwebrequest.begingetresponse(v=vs.95).aspx

we use:

```
public static ManualResetEvent allDone= new ManualResetEvent(false);
```

is that wise to use a static member in web application since it's shared with other threads ? can this cause for problems ?

1. how can I tell when all the callbacks were finished ? I need to do a summary report on the results

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. If you want to wait in main thread for completition, then this solution is not very good. First request will change event's state to "set". Therefore, main thread will continue execution after the first request completed.
2. A suggest you to use [CountdownEvent](http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.threading.countdownevent):

   ```
      using(var countdownEvent = new CountdownEvent(list.Count))
      {
          // launch requests with countdownEvent.Signal(); in the end
          countdownEvent.Wait();
      }
   ```

   You must store reference to countdownEvent inside RequestState. Also, don't forget to control timeouts - start new thread with `ThreadPool.RegisterWaitForSingleObject`.

Answer (score 3):

While you can use an event, I'd recommend using [`Task<T>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd321424.aspx) and the [`FromAsync` method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd321335) on the [`TaskFactory` class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd321401) like so:

```
// Execution of tasks starts here because of the
// call to ToArray.
Task<WebResponse>[] tasks = uris.Select(u => {
    // Create the request.
    WebRequest req = ...;

    // Make the call to return the response asynchronously with
    // a Task.
    return Task.Factory.FromAsync(req.BeginGetResponse,
        req.EndGetResponse, null);
}).ToArray();
```

Once you have that, you can easily wait on all of the `Task<T>` instances using the [`ContinueWhenAll` method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd321473.aspx) on the `TaskFactory` class like so with a continuation:

```
Task.Factory.ContinueWhenAll(tasks, t => {
     // Note that t is an array of Task, so you have to cast 
     // each element to a Task<WebRequest>.
     // Process all of them here.
});
```

Note the above returns a [`Task`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.tasks.task.aspx) which you will have to wait on or continued on when done (if your're concerned about the notification).

If you are using .NET 4.5, you don't need to use the `ContinueWhenAll` method on the `TaskFactory` class, but can use the [`WhenAll` method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh194766%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) on the `Task` class to perform the work:

```
// Note that work does not start here yet because of deferred execution.
// If you want it to start here, you can call ToArray like above.
IEnumerable<Task<WebResponse>> tasks = uris.Select(u => {
    // Create the request.
    WebRequest req = ...;

    // Make the call to return the response asynchronously with
    // a Task.
    return Task.Factory.FromAsync(req.BeginGetResponse,
        req.EndGetResponse, null);
});

// Execution will start at this call:
Task<Task<WebRequest>[]> allTasks = Task.WhenAll(tasks);

// Continue or wait here.
```

---

Note that the above was before [it was revealed that .NET 3.5 was being used](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11420252/begingetresponse-in-web-application/11420753#comment15065512_11420753).

Comment: Hi Casper. unfortunately i'm using .NET 3.5, but it's good to know that there is something to wait for :)

Comment: can you explain a little bit? how would one grab the response of a request using this method?

Answer (score 1):

I guess you're trying to do something like this:

```
int total = urls.Count;
ManualResetEvent evt = new ManualResetEvent();
ConcurrentBag<WebResponses> responses = new ConcurrentBag<WebResponse>();

foreach(Uri in uri)
{
    HttpWebRequest req = ...;
    req.BeginGetResponse(res=>
    {
        WebResponse res = req.EndGetResponse();

        // do what you need with the response.
        // maybe add it to a collection so you can report on it later:
        responses.Add(res);

        if(Interlocked.Decrement(ref total) == 0)
        {
            // this was the last response. set event.
            evt.Set();
        }
    }, null);
}

evt.Wait();

foreach(WebResponse res in responses)
{
    // report something about the response.
}
```

Note that an optimal workflow will not need an event. For extra credit, get rid of it all together and move your final logic inside the if that sets the event.

Also, this code is untested and lacks error handling, so be sure to add that in if you play with it at all.